# combine all data points of a variable into a group

Tags: r

Sorry, simple question, new to R...

With a matrix t1:

```
X1      X2

1.6875789      A

0.6041956      A

1.6835132      A

1.5923891      B

1.8011605      B

1.7421812      B
```

Running:

```
bartlett.test(X1~X2, t1)
```

Would like to run same bartlett test but with data from the two groups of X2 (A and B) distributed in two columns:

```
X1      X2

1.6875789      1.5923891

0.6041956      1.8011605

1.6835132      1.7421812
```

In other words make all values of each column specific groups

Comment: Your code is not as readable as it could be. Some guidance over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/209360

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the pointers. Should have said very new to R.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I believe you get 1 test statistic for all groups. A variance is calculated for the samples in A, and a variance is calculated for the samples in B. What is the probability of observing those two variances if A and B had equal variances? That's 1 value, not 1 value per group. I might just be confused because of how you have presented your data in the question. Try using `dput()` on a subset of your data frame, and pasting the results here. Makes it easier to reproduce your situation.

Comment: rbatt - Yes, the code recognizes that there are three data points for each group A and B in the first matrix format, and it compares their variance. Just don't know how to specify that all values of X1 are a group (i.e. A) and all values of X2 another (i.e. B) for the 2nd matrix format...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is arranged as in the second matrix, you can just use `bartlett.test` on the matrix.

```
t1 <- data.frame(X1 = c(1.69, 0.60, 1.68, 1.59, 1.80, 1.74),
                  X2 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3))
bartlett.test(X1~X2, t1)

t1_reshape <- data.frame(A = t1[1:3, 1], B = t1[4:6, 1])
bartlett.test(t1_reshape)
```